# How to make <input type="text"> elements invisible, but still displaying user input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to set `opacity:0` for some `<input type="text">` within a form.

However, I still want the user to be able to enter and see their input in these form fields.

Is there any way to make `<input type="text">` elements invisible, but still preserving their functionality?

Comment: why dont you use css.

Comment: @user111854: You mean like `border:none`?

Comment: @AkhilAravind — They **are** using CSS. They have examples of CSS code in the question and are using the [tag:css] tag!!

Comment: This is a straight-forward XY problem. Please specify your use-case, and one should be able to provide you with a better solution.

Comment: if it's invisble how will they know it's there?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to see what they type, then you can't set the opacity to 0.

Hide everything else that is visible about the input instead.

```css
body {
    background: #ccc;
}

input {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
My name is <input name=name placeholder=John>.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input:focus` then `opacity:1;`

```css
input{
opacity:0;
}
input:focus{
opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<span>input by my right side</span><input name=name placeholder="text here"/>
```

To show only the placeholder/value:

Use  `border:none;`

```css
    input{
    border:none;
    }
```

```html
<span>input by my right side:</span><input name=name placeholder="text here"/>
```

Comment: I think the idea was not to show the value on focus. The value should always be shown.

Comment: the value or placeholder?

Comment: I think both should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `input` you could also use the attribute `contenteditable`:

```html
<div class="input" contenteditable="true">Replace this value...</div>
```